# Is there a way to create a self signed certificate to Azure using openssl for enabling secured layer?

Tags: https, openssl, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, node-red

I've been trying to create a self-signed certificate for a public ip that I created in Azure to host a Node-Red instance and it seems that in Node-Red it needs PEM files to enable HTTPS.

I've have tried to create these files using OPENSSL.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

However when I try to access it, it says that the certificate is invalid.

Are there any other ways to make a self-signed certificate ??

Comment: how are you "trying to access it" and what is the exact error message?

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? in the browser?

Comment: Also since this is on Azure any reason not to use a real certificate from LetsEncrypt?

Comment: I was trying to access the public ip that Azure provided and it is returning "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your browser doesn't know to trust the certificate because it is not signed by one of it's trusted Certificate Authorities.

You have 3 options

1. If you look closely on the page there will be a way to ignore the error and continue to load the page.
2. You can import the certificate (since it is self signed) into the browers list of trusted certificates (if you tick the right box in option 1 this will basically happen automatically)
3. Rather than use a self signed certificate (Which really shouldn't be used for anything that is attached to a public IP address these days) you should use a real certificate from [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). These are free and already trusted by your browser.